# Difference between Router.push and location.assign

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my React app, I've noticed that when I use `Router.push('/')` from `import Router from 'next/router' the state of the page that I am going to isn't loaded afresh.

This means that some loading spinners whose controlling states I already want figured out when the page loads isn't accurate and I end up seeing the spinners very briefly.

However if I use JS and `location.assign('/')` - the page loads afresh and all works fine.

Could someone kindly tell me what the difference between the 2 is - and why Router.push doesn't do the same (or if there is something/some option I need to use)?

Answer (score 0):

Router.push doesn't reload the page on purpose and it should be what you are aiming for. Not reloading is one of the pros of a Single Page Application.

If the data has already loaded there should be no need to show the spinner again.

Knowing this you should build your application to take advantage of this.

[Location.assign is a built in method of the browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign). It doesn't have context of your application - like what data has loaded and what hasn't. It can't reload the page and keep any data.

Comment: Thanks - I think I see what you're saying but I don't understand what is causing it. Will need to investigate further.

Comment: Figured it out - it was the loading state I was using/logic wasn't correct. Thanks.